# Accessing base class variable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How do I access `id` from my child class?

```
class BaseClass:
    id = 'testing'

class MyClass(BaseClass):
    something = id
```

More specifically, I can't access `id` from `class:User`:

```
class BaseModel:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class User(db.Model, BaseModel):
    username = db.Column(db.String(35), nullable=False, unique=True)

    followed = db.relationship(
        'User',
        secondary=followers,
        primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id == id),
        secondaryjoin=(followers.c.followed_id == id),
        backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'),
        lazy='dynamic')
```

Comment: Did you try using `self.id`? The `self` keyword allows you to access class variables. And since your class inherits from the `BaseClass` it should have that same class variable in it.

Comment: ``self`` isn't accessible in that section of a class.

Comment: Then how about just `BaseClass.id`?

Comment: I tried that too. I get an sqlalchemy error when I try to reference ``id`` like that.

Comment: What is the error? It helps to be more specific since accessing `BaseClass.id` the way you gave in your question works fine.

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Incorrect number of values in identifier to formulate primary key for query.get(); primary key columns are 'user.id','user.test'

Comment: That error seems very unrelated to the original problem. I think that you are able to access the `id` variable fine, but are making an error when making your query, which probably merits a separate question. You might want to do a test first to see if `BaseClass.id` works fine.

Comment: It works fine. This is an SQLAlchemy issue. When I reference a column in that manner, it's treating it like a query.

Comment: Since it is an SQLAlchemy issue that is occuring, that is a different question/problem then the one originally asked in this post. The solution for how to access a base class variable has been given, but it seems your new problem now is related to calling Columns/Queries in SQLAlchemy or storing that Column object in the `id` variable which is a separate question. The exception itself is telling you that the error is caused by an InvalidRequest, not from being unable to access the base class member.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll create another question and include the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little program to test inheritance in your sample example:

```
class BaseClass:
    id = 'testing'

class MyClass(BaseClass):
    something = BaseClass.id

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(MyClass().something) # >> "testing"
```

You should be able to replace `id` with `BaseModel.id`. If not, please report what error you're getting.

Comment: I get an sqlalchemy error when I try to reference it that way: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Incorrect number of values in identifier to formulate primary key for query.get(); primary key columns are 'user.id','user.test'