# Accessing a mixin member variable (column) from the child

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble accessing a parent class member variable `id` from the child class.

```
class BaseModel:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class User(db.Model, BaseModel):
    username = db.Column(db.String(35), nullable=False, unique=True)

    followed = db.relationship(
        'User',
        secondary=followers,
        primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id == BaseModel.id),
        secondaryjoin=(followers.c.followed_id == BaseModel.id),
        backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'),
        lazy='dynamic')
```

Gives me this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'Mapper|User|user'. Original exception was: Could not locate any simple equality expressions involving locally mapped foreign key columns for primary join condition 'followers.follower_id = "<name unknown>"' on relationship User.followed.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or are annotated in the join condition with the foreign() annotation. To allow comparison operators other than '==', the relationship can be marked as viewonly=True.
```

On the other hand

```
class BaseModel:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class User(db.Model, BaseModel):
    username = db.Column(db.String(35), nullable=False, unique=True)

    testing = BaseModel.id
```

Gives me this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Incorrect number of values in identifier to formulate primary key for query.get(); primary key columns are 'user.testing','user.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class definition's body is its own scope and the names introduced will form the class' namespace. The problem (in your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52411968/accessing-base-class-variable)) with your model definition is that the name `id` has not been assigned to in the body of the class `User`, so the joins in the `relationship` definition refer to the builtin function [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id). You also cannot use `BaseModel.id` as shown in this question, because the Declarative metaclass will [create a **copy** of it to `User`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#mixing-in-columns), so it does not refer to the same column.

The solution is to use lazy evaluation: either pass a callable, or a Python-evaluable string as the join:

```
followed = db.relationship(
    'User',
    secondary=followers,
    primaryjoin='followers.c.follower_id == User.id',   # Note: the joins are
    secondaryjoin='followers.c.followed_id == User.id', # passed as strings 
    backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'),
    lazy='dynamic')
```

This works because the inter-mapper relationships of mappers are configured after the mapped classes have been declared and are used for the first time, unless explicitly configured using [`configure_mappers()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.configure_mappers).

Note that you cannot use plain `id` in the evaluable string either, but must instead refer to it using the `User` class, since it is evaluated later in a completely different scope from that of the class body, [including names from the Declarative class registry, and metadata](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/relationships.html#configuring-relationships).

The last error is the result of code such as

```
User.query.get(some_id)
```

The assignment of `BaseModel.id` to another name – such as `testing` – in the class body results in your model having a composite primary key, formed from 2 integer columns, so [`Query.get()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get) expected to receive a 2-tuple of integers, not just one integer.

Comment: NameError: name 'User' is not defined

Comment: You forgot to make 'em strings, or callables. Also in the future, don't just paste the message of an error, but give some context.